.NET Tool: Exclude framework assemblies when packing
I am creating a .NET tool project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="9.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I run dotnet pack and get a nuget package including System.Text.Json inside. I want to trim the tool to keep it small and use the .NET framework installed on client computer. I know it is possible using dotnet publish command with properties SelfContained=false and PublishTrimmed=true, but that will not create a .NET tool
